# Casting multiple different data types in C

Tags: c, casting, unsigned-integer, size-t

I am a student currently doing an assignment requiring the casting of different data types in C. Our code must be portable so the use of sizeof is important. It is also suggested we do our own casting in order to be independent from the compiler from doing so. My question is how do I properly cast multiple data types against sizeof which returns size_t which is an unsigned integer value?

Below it looks strange but I am just converting the characters into bytes incase it is compiled on different architectures where a char might be larger/smaller than 1 byte.

```
short amountOfBytes;
char b = 10;
amountOfBytes+=(short)((unsigned int)b*sizeof(char));
```

Am I doing this right? Here's another example:

```
short a, b = 200;
a = (short)(((unsigned int)b+1) * sizeof(char));
```

Last question, is it better practice to cast by size_t or should I just stick with unsigned int?

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1.

Comment: don't try to be smarter than the compiler son

Comment: shouldn't `char b` be `unsigned char b`, and `short`  be `unsigned short`?

Comment: BTW: Why `short` for a byte-count, instead of `size_t`? Also, you are aware that *an unsigned integer value* might not mean *a value of type `unsigned`"?

Comment: We have to use our teacher's header file and these variables are defined as char not unsigned. Normally, yes, but he wants us to solve these issues to gain a further understanding. Anyways, sorry for asking, its the typical response here, more questions, no sensible answers, and a chance to act out on intellectual superiority. He's a doctor in computer science so I'm pretty sure he knows what he's doing when he assigns these things to us.

Comment: What are these calculations supposed to be calculating?

Answer (score 0):

Your code can invoke signed type overflow, which is not a defined operation. Thus the code is wrong.

Also `sizeof(char)` is defined as `1`. This does not however mean 8 bits. See `CHAR_BIT`.